i have problem in using deltakronker
I want to slove the below summation.
$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \tanh ^n(r) \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sqrt{m+1} \tanh ^m(r) \delta _{n,m+1}$
I know that $m=n-1$ but if i substitute that in the second sigma the above relation reads:
$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \tanh ^n(r) \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \sqrt{n} \tanh ^{n-1}(r)$
the problem is that now the second sigma starts from 1 instead of 0 while the first one starts from 0. Also i know i should remove one of the sigmas, but i dont know which one? and how to solve this problem.

You don't just substitute $m=n-1$. Instead, you perform the sum over $m$. The only non-zero term that you get is if $m=n-1$, so that means the second sum vanishes, and you have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n}\tanh^{2n-1}(r).
$$
We need to be careful about the lower limit because there is never an $m$ that matches $n=0$, so the remaining sum starts from $n=1$.

i used this formula but it gives me nonsense results.
